# How to plot this table as multiple excel line charts?

Tags: excel

Suppose i have the following excel table :

[image]

I'm wanting to plot the line charts of (v2 , v3 , v4) based on v1 variation ( v1 should be at x-axis ).

Thank you in advance for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this steps:

1. Select datas without column names on the table.
2. Go to `insert` tab and click `scatter` in the `chart` group.
   [Insert the scatter chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftFuj.jpg)
3. Customize the chart clicking with the right button on the chart. For example, you can remove or add the connection line bewteen points.

For more information or help, you can see the Youtube tutorial ["Creating an XY Scatter Plot in Excel"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBbGBrHTMrM)

Comment: the problem i found in my situation is that the used series values are very small ( they represent probabilities ).

Comment: The solution doesn't work with the used values range.

Comment: You can try to change the Y scale and/or Y range. Other option you can add a secundary Y-axis, but you have to change the chart type, it does not work for the scatter plot. If you want try it, visit https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-in-excel-91da1e2f-5db1-41e9-8908-e1a2e14dd5a9

Comment: Thank you a lot for help ,  i used Rstudio to plot data instead !